# Waves Sound Design Competition. What do you think?

Tags: untagged

Hey,

I just attended the Waves Sound Design Competition 2011.
The task was to create the sound design for trailer.
There were only a few sounds by Hollywood Edge you were allowed to use.
And you were only allowed to use Plugins of the Waves Sound Design Suite.

Now I would like to get feedback from you about my entry to learn as much as possible:

http://vimeo.com/20391704

I'm pretty happy with the created sounds.
But now I'm not so happy with the mixing.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty good, its a lot like mine but better, I just made mine for fun when I was bored and I thought I would send it in cause I made it anyway, crappy thing is I couldn't figure out how to get the demo to download with the iLok thing so I just used the plugins from Cubase LE5 check it out if you like, you'll see its pretty similar.. 
[vimeo]20164022[/vimeo]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yet don't see that many similarities.

What is the tonal sound at 19 Seconds? 
Klaxon? Bell? Pitched down minor 3rd for the second time or through Doppler?
Many entries have this sound at this spot.

Comment: hah same crap happened with me - i dont have Ilok so I wasnt able to participate at all. I will make it another way another time.

Comment: @Jascha Viehl Haha none of that it was the "DryIceEerieDouble TEE026201" I didn't really "Design" anything it was more like editing the sounds together, and about the similarities I don't know the heart beat and the carby and the end reminded me of my entry lol.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy the kind of atmosphere you created in the opening sequence before the driver gets in the crash. Overall I think you did a great job. Here's my entry:

http://vimeo.com/20503845

Comment: I love the use of silence at the end. 

Answer (score 1):

nice work, sounds really rich and awesome,

There's a lot of low end in there and fighting eachother, I'd say it's a case of EQing different elements to have them sit in their own fq range.

Why have you taken the commentary out? I wasn't sure what yours was about until it got to the crash scene, the metal sounds are great, I really liked Mitchell's ending, the fly back into the race worked well.

Comment: @edmatthews82: 
What do you mean with "taken the commentary out"?
That it's too gentle in the mix?
In didn't felt it suited well in there as a main theme.

Comment: Well it's meant to be a race, I think commentary is quite important in this situation, I notice you have it quite low when it zooms into the mirror and it sounds quite distorted which I like, but it could be louder. I always feel sound should be able to tell the story on it's own without the aid of picture, anyone hearing this could be anything from a sci-fi film to any kind of crash. 

Answer (score 0):

Two works i ve watched from that contest and your sounds really good. Nice dynamics, clarity of sound and accents, though, there is always something to polish...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments!

I probably would do the mixing different if I could redo it.
I would amplify the tonal background at the crash shot to give it a strange ambience.
I would let the small whooshes of glass and metal parts be more present.
And I would mix the race ambience (crowd and race) up to focus on the race feeling.
I guess I wouldn't put the commentary in focus because it conflicts with the slow motion.

Perhaps I would put the collage of real-time race sounds under the waves logo,
which "freezes" when the video begins. Which I had in a previous version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jascha,

I am surprised our general rhythm is so similar on this piece. Great work. I particularly like the higher end elements in the opening ambience.

What settings did you use to make your Pro Tools output before uploading to vimeo?  I feel like I lost a lot of high and lows in the vimeo compression that I can still hear in your file.

Here's mine:
http://vimeo.com/20453237

Comment: Hey Karol,

I used the Export Video function of Pro Tools and exported with 44.1 kHz because it's in the recommendations of vimeo.

Your video is compressed and stretched.
Perhaps the reduction of bandwidth happened when you did that?!

Comment:  Yeah, I did this real quickly in between promo sessions at work. I think I went on auto pilot as I have been doing a ton of short form client approval quicktimes recently.  My clients want everything emailable. :( I probably didn't change the settings and the video obviously is a different size than my sessions around it. It definitely compressed the video as well. Dope! THX

Answer (score 0):

The winners were announced. The list is [here](http://designingsound.org/2011/04/waves-sound-design-competition-finalists-and-winner/).